# React warning useEffect missing dependency

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

In my React application I have a redux store that contains a user with the following model:

```
{
  id: "",
  name: "",
  email: "",
  isAdmin: false,
  client: { id: undefined },
  token: "",
  tokenExpiry: null
};
```

On a simple page, I am querying a database for other data associated to that user. To do so I am taking advantage of the `useEffect` hook:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // Check JWT auth token and refresh if near expiry
    auth.refresh(
      { token: user.token, tokenExpiry: user.tokenExpiry },
      // Request user "field" data
      loadFields(user.client.id, user.token)
    );
  }, [user.client.id, user.token]);
```

Upon building, React presents the `React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'loadFields' and 'user.tokenExpiry'. Either include them or remove the dependency array` warning.

If I understand `useEffect` correctly, the second parameter is the values which Reach will "watch", upon any change the component will be re-rendered (similar to how `componentDidUpdate` works)...

Whilst there are other values used within my `useEffect` call, I only want to reprocess this function when the `user.client.id` or `user.token` is changed. This is to avoid unnecessary re-renders when other parts of the user model is changed, so I don't want to add `user.tokenExpiry` as a dependency.

As the `loadFields` function is a function also used outside of from the `useEffect` logic, I cannot place it within `useEffect` so I've tried adding it as a dependency, but this causes a re-render loop as it has a `dispatch` call within it:

```
const loadFields = async (clientId, token) => {
  setIsLoading(true);
  try {
    await dispatch(fetchFields(clientId, token));
    setIsLoading(false);
  } catch (error) {
    setIsLoading(false);
    dispatch(resetFields());
  }
};
```

So what is the correct way to impelment `useEffect` in this scenario?

Comment: It's worth noting that this appears to be operating as I want it at present, but I would like to know the correct way to approach this which would not cause the warnings to appear.

Comment: what about `loadFileds` function - try to wrap it with `React.useCallback` hook like this `React.useCallback(async (clientId, token) => { // ... }, []);` and add it to dependency list. According `user.tokenExpiry` I can only think of a dirty hack: 1) create state with `user.tokenExpiry` value, 2) create `useEffect` that updates `tokenExpiry` state on some condition, 3) add this state as a dependency to your existing `useEffect`. But what is worse? This trick or a warning?:)

Comment: Sorry, I don't see your [mcve]? The code shown is not enough to understand what you're actually doing.

Comment: Thanks @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, as this is a React application, utilising Redux for state management, the only way for me to achieve a working reproducible example is to create codesandbox mockup of my application. As this is quite time-consuming can I ask if I can provide any more details before needing to do this? Ultimately I'm looking to clarification on how to use `useEffect` as a dependency with an external script which utilises `useEffect`. I am also interested to know if it is possible to exclude dependencies without causing the warning (such as I've highlighted with `user.tokenExpiry`).

Comment: If need be I'll create the full mock-up of the app, I'd just thought the scripts used and documented in the question would point to where I am going wrong. I'm happy to provide any additional information I can. Thank you all in advance for your help.

Comment: @ValeryStatinov, the `useCallback` suggestion certainly allows me to include `loadFields` into `useEffect` without causing the re-render loop issue. Thanks a lot, I will have to do some more reading to get a better understanding of what it is doing. As this was the main issue here, if you want to put this an answer, I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: Please remember that if you're writing comments to explain what you're doing: don't write comments. Update your post with those explanations/updates, and write a comment saying something along the lines of "I've updated the post". Remember: [your post is where the details go](/help/how-to-ask). Not the comment thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include `loadFileds` function in the dependency list try to wrap it with `React.useCallback` hook like this

```js
React.useCallback(async (clientId, token) => { ... }, []);
```

and add it to dependency list. `useCallback` "remembers" the function and doesn't create it on every render, thus `loadFields` stays the same across renders and it doesn't trigger `effect`, see [Documentation](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback).

What about `tokenExpiry` - well, sometimes such situations happen, I usually leave a comment, that describes why some variable is not in a dependency list.

Answer (score 1):

Either add all the dependencies to the array

```
useEffect(() => {
  // Check JWT auth token and refresh if near expiry
  auth.refresh(
    { token: user.token, tokenExpiry: user.tokenExpiry },
    // Request user "field" data
    loadFields(user.client.id, user.token)
  );
}, [user.client.id, user.token, user.tokenExpiry]);
```

Or it is likely just being flagged by your react-hooks linter, you can disable it for that line.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // Check JWT auth token and refresh if near expiry
  auth.refresh(
    { token: user.token, tokenExpiry: user.tokenExpiry },
    // Request user "field" data
    loadFields(user.client.id, user.token)
  );
// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, [user.client.id, user.token]);
```

I usually also leave a comment above the override as for the reason for it. Use this with caution as when you make any changes to the effect hook it can change what you want the hook to "watch" changes of.

Suggestion: Add `tokenExpry` to the array and conditionally call your endpoint if you can tell it is close to needing refreshing.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // Check JWT auth token and refresh if near expire
  if ( /* tokenExpiry almost expired */ ) {
    auth.refresh(
      { token: user.token, tokenExpiry: user.tokenExpiry },
      // Request user "field" data
      loadFields(user.client.id, user.token)
    );
  }
}, [user.client.id, user.token, user.tokenExpiry]);
```

Comment: I can add the `user.tokenExpiriy` to the dependency list without error... it will just cause unnecessary calls to my API as the `loadFields` function would be called when the component re-renders when the token is updated. So that's not ideal.

Comment: The main issue, is I am unable to add `loadFields` to the dependency list as it causes a re-render loop; the component mounts, `useEffect` calls `loadFiels` (which does an API call and runs `useDispatch` to update my redux store which in-tern causes the original component to re-render and so an infinite loop would be created.

Comment: Ah, do you want this to run only on mount then? Otherwise you need to trigger on something other than the values this effect untimely updates or do some conditional tests within the effect, or possibly even both, to not create the infinite loop.

Comment: No, I'm looking to run on two situations; 1.) On mount 2.) If the `user.client` value is changed in the redux store (as a user can change their dataset). I've seemed to solve the loop issue thanks to a comment by @ValeryStatinov making me aware of the `useCallback` hook.

Comment: Ultimately `user.token` and `user.tokenExpiry` are just there for auth purposes. This `useEffect` call doesn't need to know about them, as I don't need to re-render the component if they are updated... but they are a dependency... perhaps its how I've implemented the `auth.refresh()` which causes the complexity... perhaps I can abstract that is some way

Comment: @Sheixt Well, my real suggestion was to add the lint disable comment since you say the effect works as you expect it to and you just have this lingering warning. ValeryStatinov's suggestion may work, but it's just more moving parts.